# How to install english model of spacy in jupyter notebook using anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, spacy

When using python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm in anaconda It is showing this error

```
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup_cli()
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\_util.py", line 68, in setup_cli
    command = get_command(app)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\typer\main.py", line 232, in get_command
    click_command = get_group(typer_instance)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\typer\main.py", line 218, in get_group
    group = get_group_from_info(TyperInfo(typer_instance))
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\typer\main.py", line 349, in get_group_from_info
    command = get_command_from_info(command_info=command_info)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\typer\main.py", line 442, in get_command_from_info
    deprecated=command_info.deprecated,
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'no_args_is_help'
```

Comment: It looks like you have incompatible versions of something. Maybe try reinstalling everything? What versions of related packages do you have?

Comment: The errors you have posted in the question are not related to spacy!

Answer (score 3):

Go to a code cell in Jupyter notebook, then:

```
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Then do `Restart Runtime` from menu bar or `[Cntrl+M]` to refresh.

Once, you have done the above steps then try:

```
import spacy
nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```